# How to make sure my company does not own things which I created outside of work?

Tags: non-work-activities

I'm currently working third year in company that produces electronics devices (from design to end product), I'm not involved in designing, I'm just assembling them. My hobby is electronics, I don't sell anything, just do this for myself and I usually publish full documentation on the Internet.

I unsure if I signed some documents about company owning stuff I create outside of work, but I can't find anything like this in documents that I have.
What is the best way to resolve this? I'm living and working in Poland.

Comment: Read your contract that you signed.

Comment: First what makes you think your company owns things you create completely independent of your work? Second, what problems could arise if you don't even sell things but use them yourself only? Perhaps I'm not understanding your text because it's a little dodgy, you could try to rewrite it.

Comment: @puck created outside of work is not the same as created completely independent of work.  Publishing documentation on the internet is not just using them for yourself.

Comment: @puck not selling things, but giving away designs and knowledge that are valuable to your company, could be well beyond "a little dodgy" and a really big deal.

Comment: Ah ok I see, this fact definitely should be emphasized more in the original question! The formulation is what I meant to be dodgy... Of course lko must find the line between common knowledge that was gained at work but could come from anywhere and special insider knowledge that must not go public.

Comment: I would like to add that in some countries there are laws regarding directly this topic. In Germany there is the "Arbeitnehmererfindergesetz" which covers this topic. This law does say that your employee does have a claim on all "inventions" done,  even if there were invented during free time without company resources, if they would be useful to the company.

Answer (score 9):

If you can't remember what you signed, ask your manager:

> I have some hobby electronics ideas I want to work on at home, on my own time, with my own equipment. That's not a problem, is it? I don't want to sell them, just put the documentation on the internet. Of course, none of our designs or plans are included in this; it's things I'm working on myself. That's ok, right?

[If you were doing this before you got hired, you can mention that, and even describe an example of one you did before you were hired. But don't give out the URL because that will quickly lead to them discovering you've been doing this all along.]

Thing is, if your boss says, no, it's not ok, what will you do then? Because it might not be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This contract, in the US anyway, is called an "Intellectual Property and Confidentiality Agreement" or something like that. When you're signing stuff on your first day on the job, they put this one before you and ask you to sign it.  It's possible that they don't ask assembly workers to sign these things. They definitely ask engineers to sign these things.

It's a big deal to the company. They probably would remind you to sign it if you didn't.

If you kept a copy of everything you signed, this will be in your file.  Go read it.

- It may cover anything you invent or develop on company time and/or using company resources (computers, lab equipment).
- It may cover anything you invent or develop in the company's field of business while you are employed by them.
- It may mention how to work out exceptions.

You will find the rules spelled out clearly.

Most companies encourage creativity in their employees, so don't be afraid of having them find out about your personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little difficult to see OP's main concern in the question but I feel like I can make a suggestion or two.

Everyone reading this should have a pretty intimate knowledge of their employment contract at all times.  With a few exceptions, what is written on the paper you signed is all that matters in these situations.

Im not familiar with the culture in Poland but, if it were my company, the assembly line employees would be under the same kind of IP clauses as the engineers. You never know who could put a proprietary component in their pocket and walk it to the competition.

Also, while I applaud the open sourcing of the things you learn in your hobby, I would suggest extreme caution.  "Check out this neat trick I learned at work" on a YouTube channel could have you blindsided with a revealing secrets lawsuit years later (extreme example).

Comment: That’s exactly how the Guilds taught the population (friends & relatives) to read when the Church did not want the population educated - scared of the power base moving... And they were right, it did move look at the difference in power that the Church had in the 14 and 15th C compared to now. Workers came home with knowledge from work and passed it on...